# Asset validation failed error after implement facebook_app_events

Tags: flutter, facebook-ios-sdk

After implementing flutter_facebook_app_events to transfer events to Facebook, there is no problem when building and archiving, but when I distribute to upload to TestFlight, I get the following error.

[image: Errors I received]

`Asset validation failed -> FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework Asset validation failed -> FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit Asset validation failed -> FBSDKCoreKit.framework.framework/FBSDKCoreKit`

It is my build phases settings.

[image]

facebook_app_events in Frameworks folder is throwing error.

[image]

I expect to be able to upload it to TestFlight and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upload the app to the App Store by removing "*Pods_Runner.framework*" from the "Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks" section. It was already included in the ***"Link Binary with Libraries"*** section.

So it seemed unnecessary to have it in both sections.

Comment: My "Embed Frameworks" section is already empty in my project, so unfortunately I can't try your suggestion. :/